# Can´t refresh data on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this row, where I have images, the idea is to change text if image is clicked

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>
            <a href="javascript:fxContent('mision')"><img class="img-responsive" src='/images/Mission01button_@Session["UserLanguage"].ToString()@Html.Raw(".png'></a>")
        </p>

        <p>
            <a href="javascript:fxContent('vision')"><img class="img-responsive" src='/images/Vision02button_@Session["UserLanguage"].ToString()@Html.Raw(".png'></a>")
        </p>

        <p>
            <a href="javascript:fxContent('valores')"><img class="img-responsive" src='/images/Values03button_@Session["UserLanguage"].ToString()@Html.Raw(".png'></a>")
        </p>

        <p>
            <a href="javascript:fxContent('acerca')"><img class="img-responsive" src='/images/About04button_@Session["UserLanguage"].ToString()@Html.Raw(".png'></a>")
        </p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div id="maincontent" style="background-color: #fff; padding: 25px; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid #C7C8C9;">
            <p style="text-align:justify" id="content"></p>   
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Problem is when I try to select second image like "Vision", it populates table correctly but under content it populates Mission content too, and I want to display only vision content

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        fxContent("mision");
    });

    function fxContent(section) {

        var contenido = "";
        switch (section) {

            case "mision":

                contenido = contenido + " <h1 >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>";
                contenido = contenido + "<p style='text-align:justify'><ul>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "</ul></p>";



                $("#maincontent").append(contenido);
                contenido = "";


                contenido = contenido + " <h1 >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>";
                contenido = contenido + "<p style='text-align:justify'><ul>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "</ul></p>";



                $("#maincontent").append(contenido);


                contenido = contenido + " <h1 >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>";
                contenido = contenido + "<p style='text-align:justify' ><ul>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>.</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Through <span style='font-weight:bold'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <span style='font-weight:bold'>HLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <span style='font-weight:bold'>Respect</span>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <span style='font-weight:bold'>Integrity</span>.</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "<li><span style='font-weight:bold'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span> and <span style='font-weight:bold'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>";
                contenido = contenido + "</ul></p>";




                $("#maincontent").append(contenido);


                $("#maincontent").append('<div class="text-center" style="margin-top:20px"><img src="/images/Mission01image.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>');

                break;

            case "vision":
                //#Tabla
                contenido = contenido + "<table class='table table-hover'>";
                contenido = contenido + "<tr><th>Name</th>";
                contenido = contenido + "<th>Position</th></tr>";
                contenido = contenido + "<tr><td>JLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td></tr>";
                contenido = contenido + "<tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td></tr>";
                contenido = contenido + "<tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td></tr>";
                contenido = contenido + "<tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td></tr>";
                contenido = contenido + "</table>";
                $("#content").html(contenido);
                break;
```

Comment: You're not removing the old contents of `#maincontent`, just adding to it with `.append()`.

Comment: I dont undertand, can you explain me more @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before

var contenido = "";

add:

$("#maincontent").html("");

You need to remove the old content before appending the new.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on vision you use .html on content but not on maincontent so it stay with it value.

you can avoid to manipulate string in your js by just hidding or show the div with .show and . hide I think it will be cleaner.